# Corner radius in UIImageView inside UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uiimageview, interface-builder, uicollectionviewcell, cornerradius

I'm setting the corner radius of a `UIImageView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell` using user-defined attributes in interface builder. Most of the time the corner radius renders correctly, but sometimes the corners are colored in with a seemingly random color:

[image: corners filled in]

I've tried overriding layoutsubviews in my subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` and setting the corner radius there (as described in other stack overflow questions). I've also tried setting the corner radius in a couple other places, but nothing seems to work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you set `masksToBounds`property to `true`?

Comment: And what about `clipsToBounds` property to true?

Comment: yes, i tried that. The corner radius works half the time. But then when i pull down my today extension and then close the today extension, the corners reappear, filled in with a random color. This also happens sometimes when running the app, but the corners will disappear when I start to scroll in the collection view.

Comment: i ended up wrapping the UIImageView with a UIView and setting the corner radius on the UIView. Works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the `UIImageView` with a `UIView` and setting the corner radius of the `UIView` ended up resolving the issue. Still curious as to why the problem was occurring though...